# dnsmasq not responding to queries for local names

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq

I have what I thought was a simple configuration: I want `dnsmasq` to respond for hostnames in a local hosts file specified using the `addn-hosts` option.  The complete configuration looks like this:

```
local=/example/
domain=example
expand-hosts
except-interface=lo
bind-dynamic
no-hosts
listen-address=10.89.0.1
addn-hosts=/tmp/addnhosts
```

Where `/tmp/addnhosts` contains:

```
10.89.0.4       foo
10.89.0.5       bar
```

(That's a tab between the address and the hostname.)

I expect queries to this server for `foo.example` or `bar.example` to return the corresponding address, but running `dnsmasq -d -q -C example.conf` I see on the console:

```
dnsmasq: started, version 2.80 cachesize 150
dnsmasq: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-i18n IDN2 DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify dumpfile
dnsmasq: using local addresses only for domain example
dnsmasq: reading /etc/resolv.conf
dnsmasq: using local addresses only for domain example
dnsmasq: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#53
dnsmasq: read /tmp/addnhosts - 2 addresses
dnsmasq: query[A] foo.example from 10.89.0.5
dnsmasq: config foo.example is NODATA-IPv4
dnsmasq: query[AAAA] foo.example from 10.89.0.5
dnsmasq: config foo.example is NODATA-IPv6
```

If I add explicit address entries (`address=/foo.example/10.89.0.4`) everything works as expected. What am I missing? The query logging above hasn't really helped identify the problem; is there any more verbose logging I can get?

I'm using dnsmasq 2.80, which seems to be current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Fedora 31 and was facing the same problem starting with version 2.80-12.

After updating to 2.80-13 everything works fine, again!

The Fedora's change log for 2.80-13 says "Fix last build breakage of DNS" which corresponds to your problem...

I hope that helps.